# List of Steps for converting dd4t 2011 site to dd4t 2013 site?

Tags: 2011, 2013, dd4t

Can someone point me to a list of steps needed to convert a Tridion dd4t 2011 site to a dd4t 2013 site?  The content is already in tridion 2013 & published.

Comment: What things have you tried? e.g. a google search, blogs read, any effort at all?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a thread from the DD4T discussion forum regarding upgrading DD4T: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/dynamic-delivery-4-tridion/upgrade/dynamic-delivery-4-tridion/OfNFAqKY_ek/5qvdiPObMnMJ

The general list of steps is:

1. Upgrade Content Delivery as per Tridion docs: http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-0AFE5C92-9ECC-4312-AB19-DF4F57AA7FE3.
2. Upgrade the DD4T Provider from 2011 to the 2013 version via Nuget.  In Visual Studio in your solution go to: Tools->Nuget Package Manager->Manager NuGet Packages.  Search for DD4T and pick the Provider for 2013.  Also unselect the 2011 one.
3. Build, deploy and do regression testing on your site.